# Inconsistencies from PySpark collect operations - graph algorithm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, graph-algorithm

I'm comparing two codes ( a sequential one in `Python`, a distributed one with `PySpark`)  which are expected to give same results. The scope is to find the count of triplets of connected components in a graph G (V, E). The results from the `PySpark` implementantion are partially correct as some of the triplets are not detected.

I compared the input data (`Python` version: two columns `pandas dataframe`, `PySpark` version: `tuple` in the RDD and `dict` as `broadcast` file) before the final count operation and they are consistent. This is the following `PySpark` script:

```
col_a = sc.parallelize(df.a).zipWithIndex().map(lambda (x,y): (y,x)) #df.a: a series of int (nodes)
col_b = sc.parallelize(df.b).zipWithIndex().map(lambda (x,y): (y,x)) #df.b: a series of int (nodes)
# remove index and move the smaller value on left side 
edges = col_a.join(col_b).map(lambda (i,(x,y)): (x,y) if x < y else (y,x))  

neighborhood = edges.groupByKey().sortByKey().mapValues(set).map(lambda (x,y): (x,sorted(y)) if x not in y else (x,(sorted(y))[1:]))
par_neighborhood = neighborhood.cache()
br_neighborhood = sc.broadcast(neighborhood.collectAsMap())

def f(vertex):
    search = vertex[1] 
    for i in search:
        increment = set(search).intersection(br_neighborhood.value.get(i, []))
        if len(increment) > 0 :
            return vertex[0], i, increment
        else:
            return 0

triplets = par_neighborhood.map(f).collect()
```

The sequential version is based on the same algorithm, and the `neighborhood` `RDD` that I `collect()` on `PySpark` for checking consistency has same values as the sequential code. 
However, when compering the `triplets` resulting from the `PySpark` implementation, some are missing.

So far I couldn't spot my mistake.

**EDIT** :

I changed the function `f` and called it with `foreachPartition(f)` instead; the result is now consistent and the computation much faster.

```
count = sc.accumulator(0)

def f(iterator): #few f 
    global count 
    for vertex_n in iterator:
        for i in vertex_n[1]:
            increment = set(vertex_n[1]).intersection(br_neighborhood.value.get(i, []))
            if len(increment) > 0:
                count.add(len(increment))

par_neighborhood.foreachPartition(f) #call
```